# How to replace the missing values with average of ffill() and bfill() in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

This is a sample dataframe and it contains`NA`:

```
    x    y    z      datetime
0   2    3    4    02-02-2019
1   NA   NA   NA   03-02-2019
2   3    5    7    04-02-2019
3   NA   NA   NA   05-02-2019
4   4    7    9    06-02-2019
```

Now, i want to fill these `NA` values and i can do this by using either `ffill()` or `bfill()`. But what if  want to apply the average of the `ffill() & bfill()`. Then how can i do this?

The direct average `df = (df.fill() + df.bfill()) / 2` didn't work because of `datetime column`.

The end dataframe should look like this:

```
      x    y     z      datetime
0     2    3     4    02-02-2019
1   2.5    4   5.5    03-02-2019
2     3    5     7    04-02-2019
3   3.5    6     8    05-02-2019
4     4    7     9    06-02-2019
```

Comment: set `datetime` as index and do what you proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with [`df.interpolate`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+interpolate&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+interpolate&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.2144j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df.interpolate()
```

---

```
     x    y    z    datetime
0  2.0  3.0  4.0  02-02-2019
1  2.5  4.0  5.5  03-02-2019
2  3.0  5.0  7.0  04-02-2019
3  3.5  6.0  8.0  05-02-2019
4  4.0  7.0  9.0  06-02-2019
```

Comment: Should i use this approach if the two weeks of data is missing from a 5 year data ?

Comment: @astroluv I dont see any issues with interpolate. but depends on your end goal. you can check the docs to handle direction and other params